# How to port a website into a mobile version of it?

Tags: mobile-website

Is it possible to port a certain full-blown website into its mobile version? If yes, how to do so?

The question seems to be a bit vague, but I would also like to get a vague idea as to how it can be done. The scalability issues and all.

Comment: It certainly is vague :) Are you talking about providing a mobile optimised version of your own site or scraping someone else's site and reformatting it for mobile?

Comment: Both . And what links should I refer to it ?

Comment: Of course such a thing is possible but I would suggest reading some more on the process of creating mobile content. There are multiple ways to do this.

Comment: Take a loot at http://www.alistapart.com/articles/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

There are commercial services available which will make creating mobile version of your site fairly simple, if not even a trivial task. For example check out http://mobify.me/

Answer (score 0):

Some recent articles on this subject I found to be useful:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/
http://csswizardry.com/2011/01/forget-responsive-web-design/

I hope this will help in finding a good method to create mobile content.